# Background effect Same size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want make a list with a few names.

But i need put all in same size.

How i can make that background with same size using bootstrap?

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
      <span >Loren ipsum</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
      <span >Lorem ipsunis</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
      <span >Lorem ip</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/novasdream/d3fkoeee/

Comment: [Give them a `width`?](http://jsfiddle.net/d3fkoeee/1/)

Comment: hmm.. is a nice way to solve that problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set a width or min-width on those elements. Min-width is a little safer if the button content has the potential to get long. Something like this in your css would do it:

```
.btn-xs {
   min-width: 15em;
}
```

Note: 1em is roughly the width of one "M" character in the font in use, so I'd recommend looking at your actual text content to find an appropriate width. (15 is just a number I grabbed out of the air.)

Also, bear in mind that this style, if authored as above, will apply to any `.btn-xs` elements. If you want finer-grained control, you'll probably want to put a specific class on either these buttons or their containing list, so you can target only this instance.

Comment: Have some way to 'bind' width of buttons ? is nice that info about '1em'

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.btn` links `display:block` so that they become 100% the width of the parent `li`. Size your `ul` as required.

```
.list-unstyled li a.btn {display:block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d3fkoeee/4/

Answer (score 0):

a better way would be to add an id to the link a like so http://jsfiddle.net/1shzc3bh/1/ and add a width there

e.g.        `a#button{width:100px;!important
}`